# How to not send email on order place from magento soap api v2

Tags: soap-api-v2

I have created a webservice using magento soap API v2 for placing an order in magento.

For this I have used below API :

`$orderId = $soapClient->shoppingCartOrder($sessionId, $cartId);`

This API placed order successfully and sent an email to customer email address. But I don't want to send email to customer on order placed.

But I wants to send email after inovoice creation :

```
$invoiceIncrementId = $soapClient->salesOrderInvoiceCreate(
        $sessionId,
        $orderId,
        $order_item
    );
```

For this I have used below code after invoice creation :

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
```

Above code send email successfully.

How to restrict `shoppingCartOrder` API to send email on place order?

Comment: Did you got any solutions for this? @Vinaya Maheshwari